# Efficient way to update column with arithmetic sequence of numbers after delete operation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a `PresentationSlide` table:

```
PresentationSlide
    PresentationSlideId
    PresentationId
    Content
    Order
```

and example rows:

```
+---------------------+----------------+---------+-------+
| PresentationSlideId | PresentationId | Content | Order |
+--------+------------+----------------+---------+-------+
|                 123 |              3 | "bla"   |     1 |
|                  23 |              3 | "bla2"  |     2 |
|                  22 |              3 | "bla3"  |     3 |
|                 100 |              3 | "bla4"  |     4 |
|                 150 |              3 | "bla5"  |     5 |
+---------------------+----------------+---------+-------+
```

I want to maintain arithmetic sequence of numbers (1,2,3,4,...) in the `Order` column after `DELETE` operation.

For example, if I delete third row (`PresentationSlideId = 22`), values in order column will be: `(1,2,4,5)` I want to update `Order` this way:

```
PresentationSlideId = 100:  update order from 4 to 3
PresentationSlideId = 150:  update order from 5 to 4
```

How is the most efficient way to do this kind of update? Is any way to do this with using only one `UPDATE` statement? I could do this using cursor and loop, but it doesn't seems efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Order is a very poor name for a column, since it's an SQL Keyword

2) It would be a lot better if you could cope with gaps in the order (and possibly switch to using a float, so you can insert fractional values), because in your current model, every insert, update or delete is potentially going to affect the entire table. This doesn't scale well. Computing an order using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) during selects would generally be better.

3)

```
create table #PresentationSlide (
    PresentationSlideID int not null,
    PresentationId int not null,
    Content varchar(10) not null,
    [Order] int not null
)
insert into #PresentationSlide (PresentationSlideId , PresentationId , Content , [Order])
select 123,3,'bla',1 union all
select 23,3,'bla2',2 union all
select 22,3,'bla3',3 union all
select 100,3,'bla4',4 union all
select 150,3,'bla5',5


delete from #PresentationSlide where PresentationSlideId = 22

;With Reorder as (select PresentationSlideId,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Order]) as NewOrder from #PresentationSlide)
update ps set [Order] = NewOrder
from #PresentationSlide ps inner join Reorder r on ps.PresentationSlideId = r.PresentationSlideId

select * from #PresentationSlide order by [Order]

drop table #PresentationSlide
```

Comment: Ad 2: I'm not sure if using float and fractional values is good idea. As far as I know, float has finite precision, so after multiple insertion of rows after fixed one, the 'Order' factional values will start to be the same. The rest is OK.

Comment: @Lucasus - ints have a finite precision too. If floats make you uncomfortable, maybe consider assigning you initial `Order` values as multiples of 10. Either way, the idea is to allow a number of inserts and updates to be performed using available gaps, and to not have to perform a renumbering operation *every* time (you may still have to perform renumbering, but you reduce the *average* cost of the operations)

Comment: Little remark: your code works with only one presentation, I've added a "WHERE PresentationId = @PresentationId" expression, where @PresentationId is PresentationId of deleted row(s) and now it works (but only when all deleted rows share same PresentationId).

Answer (score 2):

```
;with C as
(
  select [Order],    
         row_number() over(order by [Order]) as rn
  from PresentationSlide 
)
update C set
  [Order] = rn
```